# Using R. How can I use Mutate to perform calculations on a column?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm starting to use dplyr and need some help.
I'm working on a dataset and need to manipulate the column DaH1
to create a new column DaH3.
DaH3 will be the result of deducting the second row value of
DaH1 from the first row value of DaH1 etc.
After this I should end up with a vector DaH3 with values:
4,3,5,6,6,10.

I cant see how to do this using mutate.
Also the final value in row 7 will be a problem.
I'd like to assign a 0 or NA to this if possible.
Could anyone please advise how I can proceed.

```
library(tidyverse)

originalData <- tibble(
                  DaH1=c(128, 124, 121, 116, 110, 104, 94),
                  DaH2=c(124, 117, 116, 112, 107, 101, 97),
                )

> racehorse_data
  DaH1 DaH2 
1  128  124  
2  124  117  
3  121  116  
4  116  112  
5  110  107  
6  104  101  
7  94   97
```

Comment: Is `originalData %>% mutate(DaH3=c(NA,abs(diff(DaH1))))` what you are looking for?

Comment: We can use `originalData %>% mutate(DaH3 = DaH1 - lead(DaH1) )`

Comment: Thanks very much for the help!!